# Deleting first four lines in a file in openvms ---> Dcl scripting

Tags: openvms, dcl

Suppose i have a file name Trialcr.txt

```
PAR875:FXOV003506A_02> typ trialcr.txt

Classes in CMS Library DISK_FXOCMS:[fxo.CMS.LIBS.FXO_LIV.SRC]

FXO_CR012123 "FXO_CR1232 : FXOME-sfsfsfsf dasdad "
    ABC.COM 2
    PQ.BSQL 1
```

I want to delete the first 4 lines and keep only

ABC.com
and PQ.com

Want this to be done dynamically.

Can anyone suggest someway

Comment: So would that be more accurately described as keep all but the first four lines, or keep all the lines with abc.com or pq.com? And whet have you tried, and what do you mean by dynamic

Comment: Do you know what you are looking for in the file?  It might make more sense to use `SEARCH`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ close/nolog input
$ close/nolog temp
$ temp = f$unique () + ".tmp"
$ open/read/error=error input trialcr.txt
$ open/write/error=error temp 'temp'
$ read/end=error/error=error input junk
$ read/end=error/error=error input junk
$ read/end=error/error=error input junk
$ read/end=error/error=error input junk
$loop:
$ read/end=end_loop/error=error input record
$ write/error=error temp record
$ goto loop
$end_loop:
$ close input
$ close temp
$ rename 'temp' trialcr.txt
$ goto exit
$error:
$ write sys$output "Unexpected error: " + f$message ($status)
$ goto exit
$exit:
$ exit
```

Answer (score 2):

I like to use PERL or AWK for these kind of tasks.

```
$ perl -ne "print if $. > 4" TRIALCR.TXT  [ > x.x ]
$
$ gawk /com="NR>4" TRIALCR.TXT  [/output=x.x]
```

Searching for a known to be there string as per user2116290 is fine also.
With RECENT OpenVMS versions, for this specific case consider searching for a non-match on a non-existing string and skipping 4 lines.  (Search for "" does not match empty lines)

```
$ search TRIALCR.TXT;1 "@#$%" /match=nor /skip=4
```

Jim has a fine answer in his script.
There is a nice simplification possible, if you realize how process permanent files work.
Have DCL swallow the first 4 lines, then copy the rest to a target file.

```
$ close/nolog input
$ open/read/error=error input trialcr.txt
$ read/end=error/error=error input junk
$ read/end=error/error=error input junk
$ read/end=error/error=error input junk
$ read/end=error/error=error input junk
$ COPY input trialcr.txt
$ close input
$exit:
$ exit
$error:
$ write sys$output "Unexpected error: " + f$message ($status)
$ goto exit
```

Enjoy,
Hein

Answer (score 0):

*Suppose i have a file name Trialcr.txt*

which looks like the output of a CMS SHOW CLASS/CONTENT for class FXO_CR012123. Given the layout for the output of such a command (four blanks in front of the element name) in your example a simple

```
$ search Trialcr.txt "    "
```

should print the wanted lines. However, in general, there may be as many as four blanks between the class name and its description. To be safe a one-liner like

```
$ pipe search Trialcr.txt "    " |search sys$pipe FXO_CR012123/match=nand
```

should produce the expected result for all class names. Redirecting the output will write the wanted lines (which include the version numbers) into a file.